# Variable becomes zero after one iteration,matlab

Tags: image, matlab, variables, zero

```
function complexity2imgloop_90(filename)
j=imread(filename); 

m=max(j(:))

x=m-1
u=-x
```

When I run the code above, 'x' results correctly in 255, but 'u' results in zero. No matter what I do I cant get 'u' to be negative 'x'. This only happens when working with an image and not with a matrix as an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `j` is an image that is most likely belonging to a data type that is **unsigned**. This means negative values are not supported and get truncated to zero.  If you desire negative number support, cast the variable to a supported type that can handle this... such as `double`, or perhaps `int8`.  However, I'm assuming you'll want to use this for floating point applications, so `double` should be fine:

```
function complexity2imgloop_90(filename)
j=imread(filename); 
j = double(j); %// Change here
m=max(j(:));

x=m-1;
u=-x;

....
```

## Minor Note

Using `i` and `j` as variables is very bad practice.  Those are reserved for the **complex variable** `i = sqrt(-1);, j = sqrt(-1);`.  Shadowing `i` or `j` is not recommended because it makes it more difficult to create complex numbers.  You would essentially have to type in `sqrt(-1)` to facilitate the same behaviour.  There are also other disadvantages to doing this.

Take a look at this Stack Overflow post by [Shai Bagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai) for more details: [Using i and j as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you read in the image, it is likely being read in as an 8-bit unsigned integer ([`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html)). To check this, type this

```
class(j)

    uint8
```

This means that any operations on this, will also be coerced into being an unsigned integer. Therefore when you attempt to set `x` to -254, it can't be done because `x` is an unsigned integer. You first need to convert `x` to either a floating point number ([`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) or [`single`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html)) or a signed integer ([`int8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int8.html?searchHighlight=int8))

```
u = -int8(x);

    -254

u = -double(x);

    -254
```